# Unable to debug the CRT source files in Visual Studio 2013 debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2013, pdb-files, crt

I just installed Visual Studio 2013 and tried to create a "Hello World" console C++ app.  I am trying to debug through the CRT source code but I am unable to do so.  I notice that the source files are still installed in the Program Files \ Visual Studio location but the debugger is not able to find them.  I used to be able to do this in Visual Studio 2012.  What is going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with Visual Studio 2013, the PDB files of the Visual C++ Libraries will no longer be shipped with the VS product.  They will be available only through the Microsoft symbol server.  So, you need to set the correct symbol server information in your Visual Studio options.

[image: Option to add symbol server information]

For more information about PDBs and debugger options see [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241613.aspx).